# SHRINKFILE not reducing SQL Server Express data file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, truncate-log

We have a SQL Server Express instance, where one database reached 10Gb.

We have deleted 90% of the larger db table records, supposedly clearing 4Gb of space, according to `allocation_units.used_pages`.

`DBCC SHRINKFILE` has reduced the log file, but hasn't affected data file size.
The database recovery model is **simple**.

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (datafile, TRUNCATEONLY);
DBCC SHRINKFILE (logfile, TRUNCATEONLY);
```

Are there any restrictions of `DBCC SHRINKFILE` on SQL Server Express edition?

Comment: You are using TRUNCATEONLY, which can only truncate the data file back to the last used block in the file.  Since it does not relocate any data blocks, it cannot shrink it if the last block in the file is in use.  Solution: don't use TRUNCATEONLY.

Comment: What should I use to reduce the data file to the minimum possible size? I have allways used TRUNCATEONLY

Comment: Just skip the Parameter or use NOTRUNCATE.  Warning, it could be a lot slower to run, depending on how big the DB is and how full it is.

Comment: OK, it worked, tks a lot!
What exactly is the difference on using NOTRUNCATE or TRUNCATEONLY? Is NOTRUNCATE recommended to databases using recovery model SIMPLE?

Comment: No this has nothing to do with the SIMPLE setting or that your are running Express.  TRUNCATEONLY is just the "quick and easy" setting for SHRINKFILE. It's fast because it doesn't move anything around, but that also severely limits it.  NOTRUNCATE is the full version, and it always works, but it can be very slow, taking hours or even days sometimes.  See the doc here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx

Comment: Sorry, my bad, NOTRUNCATE does not actually shrink it, so it should be followed with TRUNCTEONLY. To get both, just omit the parameter.